# Dependency injection of multiple Entity Framework Core Contexts for running queries in parallel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I have a web application using Entity Framework Core 3.1 and the DbContext is registered using `services.AddDbContext` at the start.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyProjectContext>(options =>
        {
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

I need to run multiple queries in parallel, but Entity Framework only allows one asynchronous query at a time. By reading other answers here on SO I think I need to have multiple instances of `MyProjectContext` and run one query per instance.

What I don't know to do is how to register multiple instances of my DbContext and how to retrieve them in my controllers.

```
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    public ProductsController(MyProjectContext context1, MyProjectContext context2, MyProjectContext context3)
    {
        var product = context1.Products.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();
        var category = context2.Categories.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();
        var customer = context3.Customer.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();

        // Task.WaitAll, etc.
    }
}
```

`context1`, `context2`, and `context3` are resolving to the same instance.

How can I have each DbContext to resolve to a different instance - and at the same time have them be scoped to the request?

Comment: This issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10694 might give you some thoughts

Answer (score 0):

This code would await each call before calling the next regardless of one DbContext or three:

```
public ProductsController(MyProjectContext context1, MyProjectContext context2, MyProjectContext context3)
{
    var product = await context1.Products.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();
    var category = await context2.Categories.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();
    var customer = await context3.Customer.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();
}
```

To kick them off in parallel it would look like:

```
var productTask = context1.Products.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();
var categoryTask = context2.Categories.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();
var customerTask = context3.Customer.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(productTask, categoryTask, customerTask);
var product = productTask.Result;
var category = categoryTask.Result;
var customer = customerTask.Result;
```

However, since your contexts are resolving to the same instance, this would result in multi-thread access exceptions from the DbContext.

One option would be to supply a DbContextFactory for classes where you want more manual control over the lifetime scope of the DBContext.

```
public ProductsController(MyProjectContextFactory contextFactory)
{
    using(var context1 = contextFactory.Create())
    {
        using(var context2 = contextFactory.Create())
        {
            using(var context3 = contextFactory.Create())
            {
                var productTask = context1.Products.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();
                var categoryTask = context2.Categories.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();
                var customerTask = context3.Customer.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync();

                await Task.WhenAll(productTask, categoryTask, customerTask);
                var product = productTask.Result;
                var category = categoryTask.Result;
                var customer = customerTask.Result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't generally recommend considering approaches like this to parallelize queries because it is important to consider that each of these three objects are coming from separate DbContexts so the cannot be relied on as references for anything that will be persisted to any one other DbContext. Within the scope of these `using` blocks, these entities will be proxies that are tracked by their respective DbContext, so referencing them to update another entity (on another DbContext) will result in an exception. Outside of the scope of these contexts these entities will need to be checked against another DbContext before being attached to it.

The other option is to change your Dependency Injection lifetime scope for the DbContext to Per Instance or such rather than something like Per Web Request. Configuring this would depend on the DI framework you are using. (I.e. Autofac or Unity, etc) The caveat of this though is that *all* DbContext instances would be separate from one another which would lead to all kinds of problems like above where normally things like Controllers and Services etc. that might reference a DbContext would be provided a single instance tracking the entities retrieved so those entities could be associated etc. with one another without issue. If the DbContexts are all switched to be provided Per Instance (per request from the DI container) then this could lead to all kinds of exceptions and duplicate rows being inserted etc.

What issue/concern are you facing where you believe you need parallelization of queries? Loading Entities by ID is extremely fast, to the point that unless you are including a lot of related entities, it is generally better to leave these operations as synchronous queries. `async` itself adds a small performance hit, so it is not a performance silver bullet. The main purpose of `async` operations is to free up the server thread to respond to other requests while a particularly heavy client request is being processed. This doesn't make an individual request faster, but overall ensures your server stays responsive to kick off more requests. Parallelizing requests *can potentially* make a client request complete faster, but involves significantly more complexity to ensure the appropriate response comes back, and handle objects tracked by separate DbContexts. It's something I'd only consider where I am certainly facing a performance issue on a case-by-case basis, not something I'd pursue as a convention to try and preemptively tackle an imaginary performance issue. (`async` queries add a small performance hit, and add complexity & potential issues down the road especially when intermixing parallelization)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, my code example was wrong with all the `awaits` but in reality I am doing a WhenAll, etc. as you pointed out. I'm building an API that needs to query many different tables... There are zero writes. All I'm doing is querying tables flattening to a response DTO to send back to the client. I want the response to be as fast as possible.

Comment: If you are flattening an object graph of related data, project it via `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` using navigation properties rather than loading individual related entities. If you are dealing with individual references, then still leverage projection to build optimal queries. (since views rarely need *all* fields, and this will avoid possible lazy load scenarios) `async`/parallel may not make your response any faster, especially under load for simple, fast queries. By all means compare sync and async/parallel options for total response time.